# What programmable music visualizaton libraries do you recommend?

Tags: open-source, video, graphic-design

In the era of projectors, one can produce vivid images that react to the rythm and tone of the dance music played in clubs.

(I guess there are open source libraries for creating such moving pictures, but what is the name of this genre? I tried various expressions to no avail.) UPDATE music visualization software

What are open source music visualization software that are programmable, so I could have callback functions that work on the properties of the music?

Comment: I think you want [music visualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_visualization). The question itself does not seem to look for software, so it's off-topic.

Comment: This question was nominated for re-opening. I don't see how, with the current title